# What is the best way to change 'views' with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, templates

For example, I have profile page and select with 'About', 'Photos', 'Videos' section etc., and I don't want to refresh page each time I change section, I want just to change the content of container with Javascript. Sure it wouldn't be handy to write markup of pages in Javascript file, and my idea would be to write div's of each view and display only one of them:

`<div id="about>About content</div>`

`<div id="photos" style="display: none;">Photos content</div>`

However, I think there are better ways to do it, because I don't like keeping hidden views on the page. Also in most cases content in views should be generated by script, so it's looks like job for a template engine, but I'm not sure there are such in Javascript.

So what would be the best way to implement this in Javascript. I hope my idea is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to create a Single-Page-App?

Comment: Your best way would be to load the content via AJAX and update your container. Using a front-end library such as jQuery could help you with the cross-browser AJAX they provides.

Comment: @kzhen particularly yes. for example some time ago i wrote message box where i needed many views: inbox, outbox, trash, write message, view message etc., and i wanted to have them all on one page enabled with javascript.

Comment: Sounds like a job for backbone + handlebars

Comment: @MikeRobinson thank you a lot. i realized that i wrote those views juts like in backbone, but with pure jQuery/JS only

Comment: @starovoitovs If I had a nickel for the number of times I looked at my code and thought, "Crud, I've reinvented -insert framework-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) it is a template engine for javascript.

Also, you can use [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) templates (dynamically loaded into page on demand)
It is very easy to use. (However contains other things you might not want.. but should want ;) )

Comment: AngularJS is beautiful library but it might be too difficult for someone who apparently started playing with Javascript.

Comment: @Cybrix on the contrary maybe, it should be learned in an early stage (better than doing everything with JQuery...). But maybe it is too high level indeed.

Comment: I agree and I `+1` you because IMO your solution is above others. I am sure we have all started with jQuery or anything similar though :P

Comment: I watched some videos on AngularJS, it looks pretty cool, I like in Javascript frameworks that values update themselves. Is AngularJS cross-browser?

Comment: @starovoitovs if you need a very good support in IE6,IE7 you should check it. (they dont run their tests on IE6-7)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to fetch for the views whenever the user clicks on a link.

For example, bind the click event:

```
$('#clickToSeePhotos').click(function(){
    $('#photosContainer').load('pathTo/photos.html');
});

$('#clickToSeeAbout').click(function(){
    $('#aboutContainer').load('pathTo/about.html');
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<a id="clickToSeePhotos" href="#">Photos<a/>
<div id="photosContainer"></div>

<a id="clickToSeeAbout" href="#">About<a/>
<div id="aboutContainer"></div>
```

Here is a link to jQuery's page where they provide more info and examples for `load`
http://api.jquery.com/load/

You may download the jQuery library and use it on your server. However, as @Cybrix suggests you can also point to the library hosted by Google. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). At the end this could improve performance for your users.

Comment: Provide him a link to jQuery website so he can build a workable example. You may also propose using `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`